Given graph with n vertex, what is the minimal edge count to connect any vertex pairs with at most k long way?
I have n vertices and I am looking for a minimal subset of edges, which provide an at most k-long way between any vertex pairs.
At the moment, I have no idea, where to even start it. I have no idea if it is Phd+ problem or some triviality after the first graph theory semester. :-)
Is there maybe a way to generate it (of course some simple, beautiful, symmetric way would be the best)?

It depends upon the graph...  a complete graph?  a cyclic graph?  a random graph?  a special named graph?

@DavidG.Stork Question is the minimal count of the edges.

Minimal number of edges depends upon the graph!!!.  If the graph has two nodes, there is just one edge.  Ummm... so what?

@DavidG.Stork Right. Now read the question: "Given graph with n vertex"

I have simply no idea, what context could want these wonderful close voters. The answer was very finely answered. Possibly they should read it, and so they would understand also the question.

I think the context they want concerns what motivated you to ask the question and what attempts had you made.

@FD_bfa I wanted the minimal sum investition to be able to connect 6 most commonly used USB connectors to each other. I have written a script for that, but I was curious to the math part. That was the background. How the f...g s..t had it helped the accepted answerer to write his answer? ...very obviously, the close voters only want a fake reason to close any question they want, that is all. It is a shame - and a signature of stupidity - of the whole company that they allow this.

A trivial solution is to pick one vertex to be the "hub", call it $h$, and then add an edge from every other vertex $v$ to $h$.  This requires adding $n-1$ edges.
It follows that every pair of vertices will be at distance $\le 2$ from each other, since you can go from the first vertex to the hub and then to the second vertex.  So this construction works for all $k\ge 2$.
This construction is optimal, as any graph with $n$ vertices and fewer than $n-1$ edges cannot be connected.

OMG that was really much more simple as I could have ever thought :-) I expected some tricky construction.
